# Создание кастомной callBack формы Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

Всем привет!

Буду очень признателен тем, кто подскажет. Я сейчас работаю над одним небольшим проектом, по внедрению небольшого веб приложения на сайт. Сайт на WP. 
Приложение сделано как отдельный плагин. Это приложение тянется через iframe на сам сайт. Я попытался как то прикрутить плагин с того же cf7, но у меня это совсем не вышло, поэтому я решил написать свою маленькую контактную форму (ибо другого варианта тут не вижу, как это можно реализовать). 
Если у кого нибудь есть какие то статьи, как это можно было бы хотя бы примерно нормально реализовать, буду очень признателен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал форму обратной связи используя ajax.
Всем требованиям соответствует